# How to clear all jqGrid grids on the screen?

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

How can you retrieve all grids on a page?

I'd like to iterate through each grid shown on a page and call `clearGridData()` on each grid.

Answer (score 0):

I see that the actual jqGrid ID element has the `ui-jqgrid-btable` class added to it. Have you tried iterating over all elements of that class? For example:

```
jQuery(".ui-jqgrid-btable")
```